# Mobile app scores verification

Tags: android, ios, mobile, game-development

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction here?

I have a mobile app running on iOS and Android which submits scores to a website/service where there will be prizes up for grabs for top players.

The web service needs to be absolutely sure the score submitting player has/is actually playing the game and isn't just submitting boosted scores in order to top the tables.

What would be best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by submitting boosted scores?? Is the player manually sending scores or does he/she actually have to play the game in order for the score to be sent??

Comment: Yeah as its a webservice i'm aware theres plenty of command line utilities you can use to submit web requests and therefore potentially any made up score you like, normally the game would generate a score and fire off the web request but as I said its technically possible to perform the same request from lots of different places?

Comment: Then you'll need some kind of key or token to identify a real player. I use this often in our web services at work and haven't had any trouble. You could change the key up once in a while to be safe, send it back with your response and have the client code return that same key next time a score submission takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a key or token to identify a real player. When they create an account with your server, send back a token that uniquely identifies that player. Everytime they use your web service to submit a score, if their token is valid, send them a different one, and keep track of what you're expecting next submission, if for any reason you're sent back the wrong token, you can return a fault string or simply not update scores.

You should keep a log of which accounts are accessing your service and when, this way you can spot if someone is trying to mess with your WS, and if any score gets through that is not legit (which is highly doubtful if you use tokens), then you can take appropriate measures.

Comment: Gotcha so bascially you would auth them based on username/password combo, return a new access token and then calculate a new one after each request based in part on their previous action? Also logging the data their sending with times etc allows you to spot dodgey activity since you know on average how long each game is etc

Comment: Yes. The fields sent to your web service could be for example: string username, string password, int score, int lenghtOfGame, string token. The token you send back everytime can be randomly generated, just make sure you keep track of which token you are expecting next. The token can be as long and complicated as you want because it's your client(the game of the device) that will keep track of the token, not the actual user. You can encrypt it as well if you're willing to go that far.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, my thoughts:

Each user should have their own token, known only to the app that needs passing to the service. Also, the app should send some MD5 hashed value of the score + date + a random string that can be verified on the server too.

Comment: Thanks Paul/Kiwi but what would stop someone manually submitting authentication and grabbing a token that way, maybe i'm over complicating this but I know its very easy to unpack an android apk so its not hard to figure out the processes for connecting to the web service

Comment: Just make sure you don't hard code any keys/tokens. Or you can encrypt them with an encryption key that only your code can use.